# Losing lots of money

Tags: port-royale-3

I have completed the adventure campaign, i have got port royale, tampa, port st joe, corpus cristi and roatan up and running but i am losing so much money, i am paying out more costs than i am gaining.

In the villages/cities i have income from the housing rest, but the building costs and labour costs are putting my profit into loss.
This is occuring through most of my villages and i am struggling to keep my campaign afloat.

Has anyone got any decent sollutions on how to get a village into good profit and to keep it that way.
How many residences should i build, why is there building costs? and how do i get the labour costs down?

i have about 10 trade routes active but even that cant seem to maintain the profit

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is pretty much normal in the adventure campaign.

You should start running businesses, especially corn and cotton in Port Royale. But sell them for money only as a last resort.

You might want to stop doing trade routes as they will sometimes give you losses. It's like a 50%.

If you want to really boost up your money count, you should do the administrator missions. They are not too hard and they give you a lot of money in the later levels.

Make an alliance with Spain and get letters of marque to attack other cities, but choose to conquer them. You get a lot of money from its revenue.

Comment: i did build many businesses in port royale but that was a vast reason for its loss in the town, the building costs and labour costs were far higher than what it was selling for, so i was then back at the start of how to get profit